# Running a small WMI Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to have a few scripts that I can map to run from my keyboard for quickly changing the monitor/screen brightness. After some searching on the internet, I found this script which works when I enter it into Powershell.

`$monitor=@(gwmi WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods -ns root/wmi)[0]
$monitor.WmiSetBrightness(50,0)`

After I saved it as a .ps1 file and tried running it from the file, powershell tells me: The term "path of the file" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function... and so on.

I'm not familiar with Powershell at all, can someone help with what I need to add in order for the script to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

By default you can't run a PowerShell script that is in the current directory without putting .\ in front of the script name, or calling the full path of the script.

This is a security feature.

If you are in the directory that contains the script, run it by executing in a PowerShell window:

```
.\yourscript.ps1
```

Where yourscript is the name of your script.

See here for more information: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-run.html

You may also see this error if your script has spaces in its name. If that is the case, enclose the path in quotes:

```
.\'your script.ps1'
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I actually just now found that the issue was that my directory or file name had a space in it.

Comment: I've amended my answer to account for that, for future reference of others that come across this question.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind. What can I add to the script if I want the Powershell window that runs it to be hidden when I run it by double-clicking the file?

Comment: PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden "your script.ps1"

Comment: If this helped you please upvote/accept it so that others know the question is answered.